Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \ln(k)}{k}$
I am trying to evaluate the infinite series
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \ln(k)}{k}
$$
Convergence of the sum
I have proven that the series converges using the alternating series test, but I am still unclear on how to derive the closed form of the sum.
I have computed the value numerically with WolframAlpha and found that it is approximately
$$
\left(\gamma - \frac{1}{2} \ln(2)\right) \ln(2)
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
Exact value
Here’s what I have tried:
I know that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ converges to $\ln(2)$.
1. Approximation of $H_k \sim \ln(k)$
To address the $\ln(k)$ term, I tried expressing it using the approximation:
$$
\ln(k) = H_k - \gamma - \frac{1}{2k} + o\left(\frac{1}{k}\right),
$$
where $H_k$ are the harmonic numbers and. However, this asymptotic expansion introduces a remainder term that prevents me from obtaining an exact closed-form result. Even with the main terms, I haven’t been able to derive the exact value for the principal part of this series.
Despite this, using the asymptotic form of $\ln(k)$ does give a contribution of $\gamma \ln(2)$, which suggests that it could be helpful in getting the right result, but I’m not sure how to handle the full expression.
2. Partial sums
I also attempted to regroup the terms in pairs (without changing the order of the summation) to simplify the expression, leading to something like:
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{2k}\right)}{2k-1} - \frac{\ln(2k)}{2k(2k-1)} \right),
$$
but I’m unsure how to evaluate or simplify this expression to get a more useful result.
3. Other approaches
I also tried to work with the entire function $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \ln(k)}{k} z^{k}$ or to replace $\ln(k)$ by its integral value. However, this did not give much result.
Asymptotic equivalent
The book also included the following question : determine an asymptotic equivalent for the remainder
$$
R_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \ln(k)}{k}
$$
Any suggestions for how to proceed from here would be appreciated.

Why do you think that there is a simple expression for that sum?

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1710139/42969

see the derivatives section of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

Thank you very much for for the links: so the value is really related to gamma. I am quite surprised that it involves Dirichlet $\eta$ and Riemann $\zeta$ functions, as the question was asked at the beginning of the course, and should involve a "simple proof". Maybe the author is just going hard on this one.

Using the Frullani integral $\ln k=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-kx}}xdx$ and changing the order of summation and integration
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \ln(k)}{k}=\int_0^\infty\big(\ln(1+e^{-x})-e^{-x}\ln2\big)\frac{dx}x\overset{IBP}{=}\gamma\ln2+\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{e^x+1}dx$$
and the last integral, for example, here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585960/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-log-x1ex-dx?noredirect=1

The Frullani trick works like a charm, and I think is in the spirit of the course, and its level. Thanks to everyone.
